# Ruby on rails - where clause is producing an 'undefined method' error on relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I have a model Email_address which belongs_to a User. And in my User model it says it has_many email_addresses. Consider the following console output:

---

> irb(main):073:0>`b = EmailAddress.find(2)`
>
> EmailAddress Load (0.4ms)  SELECT email_addresses.* FROM email_addresses WHERE email_addresses.id = 2 LIMIT 1
>
> => #EmailAddress id: 2, email: "w@example.com", user_id: 2, created_at: "2013-03-06 02:33:40", updated_at: "2013-03-06 02:33:40"
>
> irb(main):074:0>`b.user`
>
> User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.id = 2 LIMIT 1
>
> => #User id: 2, username: "w", created_at: "2013-03-06 02:33:40", updated_at: "2013-03-06 02:33:40"
>
> irb(main):075:0>`b = EmailAddress.where(:email => "r@example.com")`
>
> EmailAddress Load (0.1ms)  SELECT email_addresses.* FROM email_addresses WHERE email_addresses.email = r@example.com
>
> => #EmailAddress id: 1, email: "r@example.com", user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-03-05 07:26:56", updated_at: "2013-03-05 07:26:56"
>
> irb(main):076:0>`b.user`
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method user for #
>           from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
>   from (irb):76

---

Can someone tell me why when I use `where()` I am unable to then locate the User, but it works when I use find()? This is very confusing output.

Comment: `EmailAddress.where(:email => "r@example.com")` produces an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.  try to change that to `EmailAddress.where(:email => "r@example.com").first`

Comment: Bingo! Thank you jvnill! That works perfectly.

Comment: Try to use "scope" as much as possible instead of using "where" in your controller, coz it makes the code more readable/maintainable. Read more about scopes here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.where()` returns an array (specifically `ActiveRecord::Relation`). To select the returned objects you'd need to specify which object. In this case, since you're expecting one object you can do:

```
b = EmailAddress.where(:email => "r@example.com").first
```

OR

```
b = EmailAddress.where(:email => "r@example.com")[0]
```